# A Worldwide Pandemic

Tags: biology, government, diseases

Let's assume a worldwide pandemic has erupted suddenly, perhaps in a third-world country, or one that can't control what's going on.

Some things to consider:

- The virus/pathogen/bacteria is highly adaptive, so finding a cure is not an option.
- The disease has a high fatality rate, Let's say, 90% lethal.
- The disease can be spread through all mediums, however, except for air (Unless this is absolutely necessary for such a disease to spread quick enough)
- Infection rate is 1 in 6 people are infected
- Starts in a country in either Africa or Middle East; Somewhere that would cause absolute mayhem in those countries already embroiled in a civil war or other problems
- The disease itself likens a lot to the Spanish flu, in terms of Incubation time and the way it can affect anyone (Except those who are naturally immune.)

Although this question may be a bit broad, what I'm asking is: What conditions would need to happen for such a disease to become a threat, and what, would the world's response be in trying to combat the disease, but more importantly, how bad would it need to be in order for the governments of the world to fail in their task?

Comment: You're not giving us a lot of informaiton. What does "high fatality rate" mean? 90%? 80%? Does it primarily infect the young? Old? Kills anyone, even with a solid track record of health? What's the incubation time? Where is the pandemic kicking off? How many people does it initially infect before the governments of the world take note? I tried to answer, but there's really just too many angles to cover if you don't give us all this information.